# Template string literal inside of another template string literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So the code I have currently, works, but I'm receiving the `prefer-template: Unexpected string concatenation` ESLINT error, which I'd like to avoid by perhaps knowing the correct way to do this with template strings literals.

Here's the code I have now:

```
<div className={`${styles.dataGridHeader} ${styles['columns' + this.props.data.headers.length]}`}>
```

I want to apply a class `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `etc`, depending on the number of columns in the data report, so that I can apply some specific styling to those elements.

What I have works, but is there a way to avoid using concatenation and only use template string literals?

For example:

```
<div className={`${styles.dataGridHeader} ${styles[`columns${this.props.data.headers.length}`]}`}>
```

Super ugly, and doesn't work, would love a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how this behaves in JSX, but in general, while not beautiful, nested template strings should work.

Comment: Maybe this is particular to JSX, but it seems without the use of an additional variable, the back ticks in the expression would terminate each other?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error? [It works just fine in the Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3Cdiv%20className%3D%7B%60%24%7Bstyles.dataGridHeader%7D%20%24%7Bstyles%5B%60columns%24%7Bthis.props.data.headers.length%7D%60%5D%7D%60%7D%20%2F%3E&playground=true).

Comment: @FelixKling Unexpected token error, JSX terminates the expression at the first back tick, wouldn't that be expected?

Comment: @Steven: Well, as I have shown, Babel can transpile it just fine and correctly. Maybe you are using an outdated version? The syntax itself (without JSX) is valid in ES6 (at least this works fine in Chrome: `\`foo${\`bar\`}\``)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this

```
const nColumn = 'columns' + this.props.data.headers.length
<div className={`${styles.dataGridHeader} ${styles[nColumn]}`}>
```

FYI there's an awesome library called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) which applied to your code it looks something like this

```
import classNames from 'classnames'
const nColumn = 'columns' + this.props.data.headers.length
const divCls = classNames({
  [`${styles.dataGridHeader}`]: true,
  [`${styles[nColumn]}`]: true
})
<div className={divCls} />
```

Comment: I'll take a look at classnames, but you're answer was correct, apparently `${}` binds any number of variables available to it inside of the curly braces, wish there was an elegant way of doing this inline without the use of an additional variable though.

Comment: @StevenBennett: The code you have looks fine. Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".